# Testing service layer with Mockito/Spring with constructor injection

Tags: java, spring, testing, mockito

I use constructor injection so my test should look like this now.

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import com.user.model.jpa.User;
import com.user.repository.UserRepository;
import com.user.service.UserService;
import com.job.service.JobService;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserServiceImplTest {


    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Mock
    private JobService jobService;

    @Mock
    private User testObject;

    private UserService userService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        userService = new UserServiceImpl(userRepository, jobService);
    }
    @Test
    public void testAdd() {

        //given
        testObject = new Mock(User.class);  //commented line
        testObject.setName("name");

        //when
        userService.add(user);

        //then
        Assert.assertEquals("name",task.getName());
    }
}
```

Is this possible to mock like I did in commented line? 
(obviously object need more fields, but for test case I need only 1 field)

I want to avoid creating new object manually with all fields, because it has too much fields and contaings of two other classes
(id, name, surname, Address address, Job job etc.)

This is my add method in serviceImpl:

```
@Override
public void add(User user) {
    user.setName(StringUtils.trimToNull(user.getName()));
    user.setSurname(StringUtils.trimToNull(user.getSurname()));
    user.setJob(jobService.getCorrectJob());
    user.setCreateDate(LocalDateTime.now());
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

UPDATE:
With information PLOG gave me in an answer I created test like this:

```
    //given
    testObject.setId(999);
    testObject.setName("name");
    //when
    userService.add(testObject);
    //then
    assertEquals("name", userService.getById(999).getName());
```

But it still caugh: java.lang.NullPointerException

UPDATE2:

I resolved null pointer exception by removing method userService.getById(999).getName() in assertEquals.

The correct and working test in my example is:

```
    //given
    testObject = new User();
    testObject.setName("name");
    //when
    userService.add(testObject);
    //then
    assertEquals("name", testObject.getName());
```

Comment: Are all the fields used in your userService? If not, why do you need to initialize all of them?

Comment: now you can check my add method in answer.

Comment: like you can see I need atleast 4 fields (name, surname, job, date), and I would like to test it by using only name and ignore rest values. Is it even possible?

Comment: Normally, you don't mock simple data objects. And in your case, setting those two values should be totally ok, since it will be much easier to check them instead of checking their mocked values.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for answer it helped me out :)

Comment: A little detail: I would get rid of the whole `@Before` method and instead just add `@InjectMocks` above the `private UserService userService;` As long as you don't have other constructors, Mockito can create a new instance and put the mocks into the constructor automatically just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this. You don't need to instantiate the mock like your commented code though. The mock already exists because of the `@Mock` annotation along with the fact you are using the `MockitoJUnitRunner`.

To test your add method just use the mock User object as the method argument:

```
userService.add(testObject);
```

Although to be honest there is no real reason to mock the User. Just instatiate a user and only set the fields you are interested in. As far as I can see from your code having a null name or surname wouldn't break anything.

Comment: Hello Plog and thanks for the answer. I reformated code like u said. Unfortunately it brakes my code. I get java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I resolved issue and I updated question so u can check it. It was inside assertEqual "userService.getById(999).getName()" which I changed just for testObject.getName() and all is fine now :)

Comment: That assertation doesn't really test anything about the add(User) method though. It's just testing that the setter worked for the name. You should probably investigate why getById is null pointering.

Comment: In my case I think it works because I test mostly working trim (so if I set name = "   name" I get "name" after add method.

Comment: Oh yeah, thats fine then!

Comment: But your correct also. I'll investigate it for future cases.